# regex replace formula in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have json text in bigquery table. Example:

```
{"b": "text ... "text" text ..." text ... "}
```

I want to remove " from text in b and result should be like this:

```
{"b": "text ... text text ... text ... "}
```

I will be glad to receive your suggestions

Comment: I'd use REGEXP_REPLACE (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_replace), and then use a combination of ChatGPT to write a regex for you, and test it on regex101.com